# Correct way to test Angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, user-interface, testing, karma-jasmine

So this is more of a theoretical question rather than a programming question.
In my basic understanding of the Angular 4 framework a component can have `inputs, outputs and services which also interact with the store to store data`.

Now all of this, in the case of a web-app is displayed on a template. I have recently been looking at testing of such an app.

I plan to use `Jasmine` as the framework and `Karma` as the test runner on Chrome (for now).

With that said, what should I be testing for?

According to my understanding the basic tests should include some mock object handed to the component and checking if that is rendered properly on the template, mocking a service and checking what is rendered when we receive the correct response.

1. So what do I do after this? After I have tested this?
2. How is this behavior driven development? What can I do more?
3. What is a "good angular test"?

Comment: Are you talking about unit tests or E2E tests?

Comment: this is too broad IMO

Comment: @Akanksha I want to know more about the both of them.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mensioned jasmine with karma, My perspective of answering this question will be mostly on Unit Testing. Let us go one question after another

**What is a "good angular test"?**

1) Unit testing should be written by the developer not by anyone else (tester).

2) It must have both positive and negative scenarios handled.

3) All network calls should be mocked or stubbed.

4) It should pass irrespective of environment.

5) It should have be easily readable, reliable and should not test the integration.

**How is this behavior driven development? What can I do more?**

In a nut shell BDD:

1) Write unit test cases prior to your development

2) Let all of your unit test cases fail

3) Start with your development unit by unit. Pass the assertion.

4) BDD is a advancement of TDD. In BDD we should not test the implementation but behavior should be tested.

5) BDD increases the code quality as well since we create test case based on behavior.

**So what do I do after this? After I have tested this?**

Current trend as explained above, after writing the test cases start with the development. Write the assertion, even the non technical person can understand the behavior.

Answer (score -2):

You should also check if your bread-crumbs are in position, bread-crumbs are used for internal routing between pages. Also use the right path of your routing component in your app-module.

Comment: This answer may be specific to your application. Not everyone/every application has breadcrumbs.